# Compile and Run commands for swift

Tags: language-support

I want to compile and run swift language programs on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, but I don't know the commands. 
Please Help.

Answer (score 4):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install clang libicu-dev -y
wget https://swift.org/builds/swift-4.2.3-release/ubuntu1804/swift-4.2.3-RELEASE/swift-4.2.3-RELEASE-ubuntu18.04.tar.gz
mkdir ~/swift
tar -xvzf swift-4.2.3-RELEASE-ubuntu18.04.tar.gz -C ~/swift
nano ~/.bashrc
```

.bashrc will open in the terminal for editing in nano text editor. Paste the following line at the end of .bashrc.

```
export PATH=~/swift/swift-4.2.3-RELEASE-ubuntu18.04/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file being edited. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Close the terminal, open a new terminal, and run the following commands.

```
swift -version # This command should print Swift version 4.2.3.
cd Desktop/
mkdir helloworld-project && cd helloworld-project
swift package init --type executable
swift build
.build/debug/helloworld-project
```

Results:

```
Hello, world!
```

#### Swift REPL example 1

Swift has an interactive interpreter called the REPL which stands for Read-Eval-Print-Loop. The REPL can be run interactively from the command line as demonstrated in the below example.

```
$ swift -repl
:0: warning: unnecessary option '-repl'; this is the default for 'swift'  
with no input files
Welcome to Swift version 4.2.3 (swift-4.2.3-RELEASE). Type :help for assistance.
  1> // Hello, World! Program
  2> import Swift
  3> print("Hello, World!")
Hello, World!
  4> :exit
```

#### Swift REPL example 2

This example executes the same code as example 1 with two differences.

1. Everything is done in Gedit.
2. The entire code block is copy/pasted from the edit pane into the terminal pane in Gedit (Embedded Terminal plugin), and run by the Swift interpreter as a block of code instead of one line at a time.

[image]

Comment: Thank You for your answer. Your answer helped me go to the swift shell and work upon that. However, the requirement is of the commands that can simply compile and then run the swift program written in a text editor like that in 'gedit'. Unlikely, the answer tells how to work upon the shell itself and not on the text editor.

Comment: I added a screenshot of running an entire Swift program in Gedit using the built-in Gedit terminal..

Comment: Thank You for your constant help, friend. But still the commands for compiling and running are missing. The following set of steps is what I want to follow in the terminal: (1) gedit fileName.swift (2) *swift program compiling command. (3) *swift program running command. ________After this, the output should be visible at the terminal.

Comment: That's not Gedit or any text editor. That sequence is called an IDE, like Xcode (which stands for "**ex**ecute code").